# Python Kerberos, Flask-kerberos and krb5-config install on windows

Tags: python, windows, kerberos

I am tyring to install the Python Flask-kerberos package on Windows 10 but I can't get it becuase I need 'krb5-config' command I have searched about this command but I didn't find any solution to Windows 10. The solution that I found is on Linux (Ubuntun/Debian)

```
c:\Users\usuario\Desktop>pip install Flask-kerberos
Collecting Flask-kerberos
Collecting kerberos (from Flask-kerberos)
  Using cached 
(..)
Building wheels for collected packages: kerberos
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for kerberos ... error
  Complete output from command 
"C:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\usuarioPA~1.CAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3rib23c5\\kerberos\\setup.py'
;f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__)
;code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
;f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d 
C:\Users\usuarioPA~1.CAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-6uchci3l --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'kerberos' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD 
"-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda\include"
 "-IC:\Program Files\Anaconda\include" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" 
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt"
"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" 
/Tcsrc/base64.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/base64.obj 
'krb5-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Could you help me? I need to install that package on Windows

Thanks
Regards.

Comment: Did you try the Anaconda distribution of Python? It's way better at handling this kind of dependency issues, since all packages are pre-built. For "exotic" packages you can still use `pip` on top of the standard stuff managed by `conda`.